# User Limit Reached when connection is requested in pool of mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection, pool

In node js,I have created a pool for database connectivity

```
var pool = mysql.createPool( // use a pool for multiple connections
{
  connectionLimit : 4,
  waitForConnections : true,
  queueLimit : 0,
  host     : hostName,
  user     : userName,
  password : passName,
  database : databaseName
});
```

After making four connections the code works fine.
But after five connection requests are queued in pool for connection and then I make a connection request as

```
pool.getConnection(funtion(err){
  if(err)
    console.log('[error] with connection'+err);
});
```

Then Error occurs --->

```
[error] with connection Error: ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED: User 'b1312146aa0cc6' has
exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 4)
```

Comment: Any answers.... I am hitting this snag too

Comment: The fix was, everytime I was using the connection to execute a query a new connection was made, I had to terminate/close the connection once I execute the query

Comment: I called connection.release() sometimes it still hits a snag and I have to switch it from async to a syncronous call to avoid multiple db connections... thought the pool would handle that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 4,
    waitForConnections: true,
    queueLimit: 0,
    host: hostName,
    user: userName,
    password: passName,
    database: databaseName
});

var sql = 'select * from bag where id = ?';
var args = [1]

pool.query(sql, args, function(err, result) {
    console.log('result:', result);
})

pool.query(sql, args, function(err, result) {
    console.log('result:', result);
})

pool.query(sql, args, function(err, result) {
    console.log('result:', result);
})

pool.query(sql, args, function(err, result) {
    console.log('result:', result);
})

pool.query(sql, args, function(err, result) {
    console.log('result:', result);
})

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Lellansin.                                                            If I do this,all the query use the same connection and takes lot of  time to produce result